# Access 2013 locking other users out when linked to a Sharepoint list

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2013

I have an Access 2013 database that is stored on a remote computer.  I do not have it set in a back-end/front-end setup.  I have a SharePoint 2010 list linked to it as a linked table.  I have 2 users that need to have access to the database at all times, others may need in it at a later date.  When I link the table, only 1 user can be in the database at a time.  Prior to adding the linked table, all users were able to use the database simultaneously.  Now, after the first person gets into the database, subsequent users get the message:

> The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' on machine '[computername]' that prevents it from being opened or locked.

For testing purposes, I tried creating a blank database that is connecting to that same table and tried to open it from another computer.  I received the same error and all that is in there are the 3 tables needed for the SharePoint list.

Is there anything I can do to be able to have multiple users in my database again?  I have full control to make changes as needed to the database, but I have no access to be able to change anything server side on SharePoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the 2010 SharePoint caching format.

You can avoid this behavior by going to *Options* -> *Current database* -> *Caching Web Service and SharePoint tables*, and untick *Use the cache format that's compatible with Access 2010 or later*.

Note that the different cache formats come with different features. The old (XML-based) cache format supports multiple users, the new (table-based) one doesn't. The old cache format can be taken offline manually and needs to be synchronized manually if offline, the new one automatically goes offline if SharePoint is unavailable and synchronizes automatically as soon as SharePoint becomes available. The new one supports adding fields in table view, the old one doesn't.

Through VBA you can mix caching formats for different lists, but that's generally not recommended.